# Print a View without buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing

How can I print a View without showing the buttons on the printed paper?

**Edit:**
Currently my button simply does this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Drucken" onclick=" window.print(); " />
<input type="submit" value="Schließen" onclick=" window.close(); " />
```

Comment: This is not a _real question_ for Stackoverflow. Did you try anything? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [css file for printing](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/), and hide the buttons (`display:none`) in that css file.

Comment: Actual curiosity how would you set the print style dynamically? I mean how would you catch the call to print to make the style change?

Comment: You don't need to do very much, just add media="print" to your print css file link and the file will be used when you print the page.

Comment: how do I need the style to be defined? #print {} ?

Comment: The css file for printing is exactly the same as any other CSS file, except media="print" in the link to the file (in the head section)